# How to get a path and user define filename using filedialog which file is not exist c#?

Tags: c#

I need to get folder path and a file name. I will create any type of file with the file name in the folder location. If a file with the user define name already exist need to overwrite the file.
Anyone can give any idea. How can do this in c# technology.

SaveFileDialog have been used. But it hasn't the overwrite option.

[If the file already have exist.Prompted message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK0ul.png)

Comment: So upon clicking "Save", do a check to see if the file exists (`if (File.Exists(filePathHere))`) and if so, just delete the file and create a new one with the same name.

Comment: The SaveFileDialog should have a property called `OverwritePrompt`. Are you setting this value?

Comment: @osman From the screenshot you've added, it looks like the problem was actually about folder permissions, and not about overwriting existing files.

Comment: @osman please also consider upvoting my answer if it helped you 

Comment: @cramopy i have no permission for upvoting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `OpenFileDialog` with the option `CheckFileExists` set to `false` and use this instead of the `SaveFileDialog`.
Then you get a filepath and now can check the way you've already done it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the property `OverwritePromt` is set to `true`. This is the default value, but if it is set to `false`, the user will not be warned about overwriting an existing file.

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

// If the user selects an existing file, this will promt a warning about overwriting the existing file.
dialog.OverwritePrompt = true; 

var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

if (result.HasValue && result.Value == true)
{
    // Save the file...
}
```

Comment: `true` is default value for `SaveFileDialog.OverwritePrompt`

Comment: @EgoPingvina, yes, I also mentioned this in my answer. My guess was that OP was experiencing this behaviour because the property was set to `false`. But OP has since supplied a screenshot, which suggests that the actual problem was about folder privileges, and not about overwriting existing files.